# Pass self as CommandParameter?

Tags: wpf, xaml, .net-4.0

I am trying to bind the CommandParameter of a command on a TreeView to the TreeView itself's selected item without naming the TreeView.

Code:

```
<TreeView>
    <ACB:CommandBehaviourCollection.Behaviours>
        <ACB:BehaviourBinding Event="SelectedItemChanged" Command="{Binding CmdSelectedItemChanged}" CommandParameter="{Binding SelectedItem, Source={RelativeSource Mode=Self}}"></ACB:BehaviourBinding>
    </ACB:CommandBehaviourCollection.Behaviours>
</TreeView>
```

I am using [AttachedCommandBehaviour](http://marlongrech.wordpress.com/2008/12/13/attachedcommandbehavior-v2-aka-acb/) in the above example.

Can someone explain how I can achieve this?

Thanks,
Alex.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try out following:

```
<ACB:BehaviourBinding 
   Event="SelectedItemChanged" 
   Command="{Binding CmdSelectedItemChanged}"  
   CommandParameter="{Binding 
        Path = PlacementTarget
        RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, 
        AncestorType={x:Type TreeView}}}" />
```

Comment: @Alex Hope O'Connor: is it helped?